# Android Eclipse dev enviroment not building dependent libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, build, dependencies

I've got a project which has a dependency on a library. I added the library to the main project successfully in the "Android" project properties of the main project.

Once everything is compiled everything works fine. The problem is that if I make a change to the library I would expect that when I build project referencing that library it would detect that the library has changed source files and build it too. It doesn't. I have to manually build the library, then the main project. Is there something I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

1) Open the properties of the library project, select **Android** property and ensure that the **Is Library** checkbox is ticked.

2) Open the properties of your main project, select **Java Build Path**, click the **Order and Export** tab, then ensure that the **Android Private Libraries** checkbox is ticked.

3) Build your main project again to see if the changes in the library project are refreshed.

Comment: Both of these are set correctly. Still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: What Android build version do you have? Another thing you could try is construct an ANT script and force the library project to be built before the main project is built. Search SO for an example of an ANT script.

Comment: Android SDK Tools 22.0.5
Android SDK Platform-tools 18.0.1
Android SDK Build-tools 18.0.1

I suppose I could go the ANT route, but this is a pretty basic use case that an IDE should handle.

Comment: If you are using Android SDK 22.0.5, do you also use Android Development Tools (ADT) 22.0.5? If not, make sure you do. Different versions of SDK and ADT tend to lead to unforseen and often hard-to-troubleshoot errors / anomalies.